# Companion colormap for text highlight color

Tags: color, print-design, typography, color-theory, design-principles

Edit:
I am looking for resources (articles, books, posts) which study the choice of a single color to highlight text and a sequential color for two and three dimensional plots such that both are harmonic.

Here is an example where I used [pgfplots](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=en) **hot** colormap for the surface plot and a simple **red** to highlight text.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Data Visualization}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{center}
\textsf{remperature \color{red} 37.1}
\end{center}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view={55}{45},width=.7\linewidth,height=6cm,axis lines=none]
    \addplot3[surf, samples=41, domain=0:360] {sin(x)*sin(y)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am looking for studies that say something like "... the highlight color should be 80% of the maximum color in the sequential colormap."

Comment: you say "two and tree" do you mean "two and three"?  Also, though I like the question, others may deem this as opinion-based which is off-topic here.  Your terminology of "I am looking for a colormap for two and tree dimensional plots that looks good" would be the hammer to the question.  I would encourage you to make an [edit], if you can, with a narrow question so that you will receive an answer that isn't biased and would help others.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to communicate with that particular visual? Specific colors will be primarily opinion based, but we could maybe help with contrast/vibrancy and such. Right now, that visual looks quite nice if the goal is to emphasize the difference between the red and blue areas.

Comment: I edited my question to make it less opinion based.